# Set global axios token using SWR and iron-session, next.js

Tags: authentication, next.js, axios, swr

I have my authentication token stored in iron-session and I'm using useSWR hook to fetch my token. But i can't use useSWR hook in my global config file. I also don't want to use cookies or local host as they are not as safe as iron-session. How can i access my token?

Global axios config.

```
export const publicRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
});


publicRequest.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    if (config != undefined && config.headers != undefined) {
      config.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
      if (token) {
        config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
      }
    }

    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Swr hook

```
const { data: user, mutate: mutateUser } = useSWR("/api/user");
```

I'm also using react-query to fetch all of my apis so that's why i need the axios config.

I have tried setting publicRequest headers in other files, It works with login function but when i reload the page it stops working, calling it in UseEffect of the _app did not work either.